# Get first item of 2d array entries in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I got a postgres function that gives me this (sample) 2D array

```sql
{{0.82,60.64,1006},{2.0,59.64,1006},{9.9,60.304,999}}
```

I want to get the first item of each row, like this:

```sql
{0.82,2.0,9.9,}
```

Any way of doing this directly on Postgres/SQL? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostrgeSql provides array ops you want. Demo

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
    id int,
    va decimal[3][3]
);
INSERT INTO sample
    VALUES (1, '{{0.82,60.64,1006},{2.0,59.64,1006},{9.9,60.304,999}}');

select id, array_agg(v) res
from (
  select id, unnest(va[:][1:1]) v
  from sample
) t
group by id
```

Returns

```
id  res
1   {0.82,2.0,9.9}
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks, could you explain a bit what `va[:][1:1]` is doing?

Comment: @John,   see the manual [Slices of an array, or subarrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)